# Are there any Achievement and Leaderboard services for gamers and game developers?

Tags: application-development

are there any Achievement and Leaderboard services for Ubuntu like XBOX LIVE? Also would it be open for game developers of any kind?

Comment: something like this: http://playtomic.org/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. Certaintly not installed by default (like Game Center is on OS X).

Note that Steam is an option, now that it's on Linux. I'd go for that, especially since it's cross-platform. However, that's just my personal opinion.